# SQL Server - get last year average, current year monthly average, and current year total average

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a simple query in SQL Server to get current year average grouped by month, so it returns me 12 rows. I need to put in the first row, the TOTAL average from last year, and in the last row, the TOTAL average from current year, so it would become 14 rows.

[image: current result]

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS mes 
FROM 
    WorkOrder 
WHERE 
    workOrderSource = '02'  
    AND YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018 
    AND conclusionDate IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(workOrderDate);
```

How should I pass dynamic year, and add the 2 extra rows into my query with past and current year totals?

The result should have 14 rows; the FIRST row will be the average of TOTAL  from last year, the LAST row, will be the average TOTAL from the current year

Comment: Have you tries Union for combining the result-sets of the three required queries? By Dynamic year do you mean utilizing something like GetDate()?

Comment: I did used the unions, but I couldn't achieve the wanted result, I tried the getDate function as well, but I don't seem to find a way to make it work

Comment: Once you get this working, i would suggest adding a column to say what the number is.

Comment: @MatheusBatista . . . Please provide the results that you want.

Comment: this data will be sent to a chart, so it only requires the numbers, I'm retrieving this sql from a c# api, but the chart requires the 14 indexes

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited

Comment: On **which column** is **average** calculated? Why are using **count** in your query while you are asking for **average**? And what do you mean by **total average**? I mean what is the difference between **average** and **total average**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS mes, null
    FROM WorkOrder 
    WHERE workOrderSource = '02'  
      AND YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
      AND conclusionDate IS NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(workOrderDate)
    FROM WorkOrder 
    WHERE workOrderSource = '02' 
      AND YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2019
      AND conclusionDate IS NULL 
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(MONTH(workOrderDate))
    ORDER BY COALESCE(MONTH(workOrderDate), 13)
```